Please recommend me books on Geometry in the style of Gelfand series
My first serious encounter with Geometry has been reading the book "Geometry" by Tatiana Alekseyevskaya (Gelfand).
An amazing book, are you aware of other books on Geometry in the same style? It is not heavily based in axioms, there are lots of pictures in the book. It helped me to see Mathematics like in a free style fashion, since there were no rules to memorize. Knowledge was constructed from the ground up, points and lines.
What else is out there? I was reading some stuff about some guy making a geometric interpretation of Einstein's theory of relativity. I mean, if it helps I tell myself I am interested in Computer Graphics, but the aforementioned book really got me into geometric constructions using pen, paper, straightedge.
It is not my interest to feel intellectual, I just want to be in awe, I can't say absent of reality because Geometry models our space, it is very real if you will. I want to see it with my own eyes as Judea Pearl said once.
I may sound super naive, but yeah, I am just getting started.
Thanks a lot!

Russian books are indeed often very didactic. A reason for that is that University professors were animating groups of "gifted" secondary shool students. I have different titles in mind, but the one that I would privilegize is "Geometry, a comprehensive course" by Dan Pedoe (Editor : Dover 1988) ; it covers well most fundamental themes of classical geometry.
